# import local python module in HTCondor

Tags: python, import, module, submit, condor

This concerns the importing of my own python modules in a HTCondor job.

Suppose 'mymodule.py' is the module I want to import, and is saved in directory called a XDIR.
In another directory called YDIR, I have written a file called xImport.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
print sys.path
import numpy
import mymodule
```

and a condor submit file:

```
executable = xImport.py
getenv = True
universe = Vanilla
output = xImport.out
error = xImport.error
log = xImport.log
queue 1
```

The result of submitting this is that, in xImport.out, the sys.path is printed out, showing XDIR.  But in xImport.error, there is an ImporError saying 'No module named mymodule'.  So it seems that the path to mymodule is in sys.path, but python does not find it.  I'd also like to mention that error message says that the ImportError originates from the file

```
/mnt/novowhatsit/YDIR/xImport.py
```

and not `YDIR/xImport.py`.

How can I edit the above files to import mymodule.py?

Answer (score 0):

When condor runs your process, it creates a directory on that machine (usually on a local hard drive).  It sets that as the working directory.  That's probably the issue you are seeing.  If XDIR is local to the machine where you are running condor_submit, then it's contents don't exist on the remote machine where the xImport.py is running.

Try using the .submit feature transfer_input_files mechanism (see http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.6/2_5Submitting_Job.html) to copy the mymodule.py to the remote machines.